# Devise breaks migrations in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, capistrano

I'm using devise 2.1.0. On dev, things are great. I just tried doing a cap deploy:migrations to a new server i setup in EC2 and its erring out at a devise migration. I'm using rvm with the ruby 1.9.3 running. My database is MySql and its running through Amazon RDS. The migration it errs on is:

```
def self.up
 change_table(:users) do |t|
  t.database_authenticatable :null => false
  t.recoverable
  t.rememberable
  t.trackable
 end

 add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
 add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
```

end

with this error: undefined method `database_authenticatable' for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Table:0x00000004eb8968

i've confirmed the devise gem is installed on the server already. I've also tried running the migration directly from the server and it fails.

Any ideas whats going on?

Comment: Devise 2.0 removed the database migration helpers, you need to list the database fields yourself: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the migration method `database_authenticatable` has been removed from devise. They were deprecated in 2.0 and removed in 2.1.

You have to create the required fields explicity. For example

```
def self.up
 change_table(:users) do |t|
   t.string :email
   t.string :encrypted_password
   t.timestamps
end
```

See [How To: Upgrade to Devise 2.0 migration schema style](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style) from the Devise wiki.